# How to filter data coming from eventHub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

Lets say I have data in event hub which contains messages of a json parsed string.

```
obj = {
  string id;
  string password;
}
```

Is there a way to get only those messages which have a specific Id, say 123, in a .net console application.
Currently, it receives all data for a timeperiod.

```
await foreach(PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumer.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(firstPartition, startingPosition, cancellationSource.token)
{
  byte[] eventBodyBytes = partitionEvent.Data.EventBody.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any filtering of events needs to happen in the application as part of its logic as events are processed.

Event Hubs represents a stream of data that is treated by the service as opaque; it does not inspect or mutate events and, as a result, is completely ignorant of the structure of your data.

A reader may ask to start from any point in the stream.  Once the reader is attached, it can only read forward in the stream and contiguously.  It is not possible to jump around within the stream nor skip over any events.